# Was an Alien body found in the Republic of Buryatia?

Tags: aliens, ufo

According to CNN iReport article "[Alien Body Discovered in Russia After Reported UFO Crash](http://ireport.cnn.com/docs/DOC-592395)":

> Around one month ago this publication reported on a major UFO event that occurred in the region of Irkutsk in Russia's Siberia. Hundreds of villagers saw a huge object, glowing pink and blue, hurtle towards Earth before loudly impacting the ground  in a wooded area . The event received widespread coverage in Russia and was reported by Inter-fax, Russia's government news agency. In the West the event was completely ignored if not deliberately kept from public view.
>
> An enormous team of government officials, including military personal, secret service agents and science ministry officials made their way to the UFO crash site within hours of the event occurring.
>
> Now it seems a video has been leaked onto the Internet showing a dead Alien found in the Republic of Buryatia, not far from the site of the UFO crash.
>   Some of the Translation:
>
> "we found him over there"
>
> "We found him around two hours ago"
>
> "It must have been lying here for days"
>
> I first learned of this from Allnewsweb.com.  Now much of the major media is covering it as well.

Is this yet another Alien hoax?

Comment: Wait, this was on *CNN*? Really?

Comment: @mmyers:  You obviously don't watch The Daily Show with Jon Stewart.  =P

Comment: @mmyers: note the 'iReport' part

Comment: @Reid: Oh, yes, that must have been explained in the popup that I closed immediately because it was a popup.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Russia Today News reports](http://rt.com/news/dead-alien-siberia-body/) (Apr 19):

> A video of what was claimed to be a mutilated alien corpse, which scored hundreds of thousands of views on YouTube, has turned out to be fake.
>
> The tiny “dead alien” is just skin from chicken filled with bread, reports the website 7d.org.ua. Police questioned the men who claimed to have found the “body” and they allegedly confessed to creating it themselves.

Answer (score -1):

And this is why I don't watch CNN.  Poor quality video, no effort at validation, etc. etc.

There are a lot of reasons to be skeptical of this.  For one the skin color and patterning is similar to any number of historical desicated corpses found in [bogs](http://www.citylife.co.uk/news_and_reviews/news/12719_lindow_man_display_wins_award), [ice](http://echostains.wordpress.com/2010/03/09/preserved-in-time-otzi-the-iceman/), etc.  For another, the "body" is something any a half decent [special effects artist](http://www.myvpal.com/fake-corpse-dead-body-halloween-bfx/) could produce.

The simplest explanation is that it's a hoax.  The next best is that perhaps the crash unearthed a preserved body.  There's no excuse for this sort of news "story" to even be published.

Comment: While I completely agree with every single of your thoughts posted here, these are still just thoughts. I'd say should go into comments, not as an answer.

Comment: They are reasonable points for a skeptic, IMO.

Comment: They certainly are. Like I said I do agree with them. Every reasonable person would. All I'm saying is answer should really answer the question, as in "Yes", "No", "Nobody Knows" [citation] [citation] [citation] [source] [source] [source]. Like your answer on hypersensitivity, which was perfect in my opinion. IMO my point is reasonable for a skeptic too ;)

Comment: Sejanus - http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/777/untruthable-questions.  While this did turn out to have a good negative proof (thanks Oddthinking), it's a problematic position (see link).

Comment: In defense of CNN, this was an "iReport", a user-submitted "news story" that CNN explicitly states that they don't vet (unless it's a CNN iReport, which then begs the question of what's the difference between that and a "regular" CNN report...). I deliberately ignore anything on "iReport" that can't be verified elsewhere, especially if it includes claims about media deliberately ignoring a supposedly major story -- that's a huge red flag that it's probably a hoax.